# Phpmailer doesnt work in joola on altervista.org Host

Tags: joomla, phpmailer

I have a form in a joomla website on altervista.org and I use phpmailer to send the output of this form (quote) throught email.

But when I load the page it occurs this error

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
'http://lindoelinda.altervista.org/reception2/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'
(include_path='.:') in/
membri/lindoelinda/plugins/system/sourcerer/helper.php(607) :
runtime-created function on line 481
```

the file is well PHPmailer is located in that folder but it seems tell me that file doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Joomla! jMail class and not phpmailer. There's no point in using Joomla! CMS if your not using its classes and functions.

As it is a simple form you would be best just getting a new form component like rsforms to handle this and remove your custom setup.